# webdriver плюс phantomjs (nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Привет! Не могу с ходу найти.
Если я хочу хром подключить, я скачаю пакет [chromedriver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chromedriver) и сделаю:

```
require('chromedriver');
this.driver = new webdriver.Builder()
  .forBrowser('chrome')
  .build();
```

А какой драйвер я из npm могу взять и подключить для phantomjs?
Не хочу хранить в проекте драйвера. Хочу из npm их брать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для будущего поколения... В исходниках webdriver нашел решение...

Берем нужные пакеты

```
npm i phantomjs-prebuilt chromedriver selenium-webdriver --save
```

Код для фантома:

```
let phantomjs = webdriver.Capabilities.phantomjs();
phantomjs.set("phantomjs.binary.path", require('phantomjs-prebuilt').path);

let driver = new webdriver.Builder()
  .withCapabilities(phantomjs)
  .build();
```

Код для хрома

```
let chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
chrome.setDefaultService(new chrome.ServiceBuilder(require('chromedriver').path).build())

let driver = new webdriver.Builder()
  .forBrowser('chrome')
  .build();
```